# and NTLM in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I disable anonymous browsing of an MVC site and only allow NTLM authenticate users access, I presume any page simply decorated with the

```
[Authorize]
```

attribute will pass, so if I want to only allow user limited access to parts of the site, I'll need to do add them to an AD group and use that to apply the filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Authorize] by default will only look for IsAuthenticated flag. So yes, applying[Authorize] without additional param will allow all logged in users.

To limit, you can use Roles/Group (NOT OUs). It will check the IsInRole (from IPrincipal).

Comment: How does a Role differ to group membership?

Comment: My bad - I meant "OU"s (organizational unit) - NOT group. I edited my answer to reflect this.